# Recording and Playing a voice works great in Simulator but not in my iPhone

Tags: swift, swift2, avaudioplayer

I'm using AVFoundation for recording and playing voice. The application works great on the Simulator. However, in my iPhone 5S (running IOS 9) it records the voice greet, but it doesn't play the voice. I always get an error while playing the recorded voice (The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -39.)")) and the next line (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value).

Then, I found the error in this line of code:

```
self._SoundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: getFileURL())
```

**"it always throws an error"**

Here is the getFileURL() code:

```
func getCacheDirectory() -> String {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

    return paths[0]

}

func getFileURL() -> NSURL{
    let path  = (getCacheDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

    let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    return filePath
}
```

And here is the setup recording file code:

```
    func setupRecorder(){

    let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(44100.0)),
        AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)),
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 2),
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.High.rawValue)),
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(320000))]

    do {
        _soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings)
        _soundRecorder.delegate=self
        _soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        print(getFileURL())

    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }


}
```

**"NOTE:
when I use print line for the path while create recorded file and playing file the exactly the same but I have no idea why it throws an error "**

Comment: Did you verify that while recording the delegate methods are getting called, and your recording completely successfully in first place?

Comment: Yes the delegate method is getting called, and  in my iPhone when I press record and stop recording no error shown. but i f I want to play it the error appears. @Shripada

Comment: Can you ensure the audio file does get created?

Comment: well, when I put print(getFileURL()) in both setup recorder and before create soundReorder, it shows the same path ending with the file name. How can I ensure the audio file does get created? @Shripada

Answer (score 1):

I removed getCacheDirectory() and  getFileURL() method and I added this code down instead and it works great

```
let fileManager =      NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).first
    let soundURL = fileManager!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("audio.m4a")
```